SwiftUI: How to correctly navigate in TabView and NavigationStack using NavigationPath?
I'm experiencing a problem using programmatic navigation using TabView and NavigationStack.
I have a TabView with a $selection pointing to a NavigationPath in an environmentObject. I also have two views to tab to. When clicking on a navigationLink item, a DataDetailView opens. Then switching to the second tab, navigationPath should be deleted. When programmatically navigation from tab 2 to tab 1 and changing the navigationPath, an empty view is displayed instead of my DataDetailView(someItem):
Expected behavior: SomeView1 -> (Clicking on item) -> DataDetailView -> (changing tab) -> SomeView2 -> (clicking button) -> DataDetailView(someItem)
Experienced behavior:  SomeView1 -> (Clicking on item) -> DataDetailView -> (changing tab) -> SomeView2 -> (clicking button) -> empty view
Can someone explain this behavior? I haven't been successful googling the problem. :/
I could probably do this with a binding of NavigationPath, but in my full app, an environmentObject would be beneficial.
Thanks in advance!

import SwiftUI

struct MyData: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    let name: String
}

class AppManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tabSelection: Int = 1
    @Published var navigationPath = NavigationPath()
}

class DataManager: ObservableObject {
    static let instance = DataManager()
    
    @Published var dataArray = [MyData(name: "Data1"), MyData(name: "Data2"), MyData(name: "Data3"), MyData(name: "Data4")]
}

struct NavigationTest: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var appManager: AppManager
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $appManager.tabSelection) {
            SomeView1()
                .tabItem { Text("View 1") }
                .tag(1)
            SomeView2()
                .tabItem { Text("View 2") }
                .tag(2)
        }
    }
}

struct SomeView1: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var appManager: AppManager
    @EnvironmentObject var testData: DataManager
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $appManager.navigationPath) {
            List {
                ForEach(testData.dataArray) { data in
                    NavigationLink("\(data.name)", value: data)
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: MyData.self) { data in
                DataDetailView(data: data)
            }
        }
        .onDisappear {
            if !appManager.navigationPath.isEmpty {
                appManager.navigationPath.removeLast()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DataDetailView: View {
    let data: MyData
        
    var body: some View {
        Text(data.name).background(.yellow)
    }
}

struct SomeView2: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var appManager: AppManager
            
    var body: some View {
        Button("Segue to someItem") {
            let someItem = DataManager.instance.dataArray[2]
            appManager.navigationPath.append(someItem)
            appManager.tabSelection = 1
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    @StateObject var appManager = AppManager()
    @StateObject var dataManager = DataManager.instance
    
    return NavigationTest()
        .environmentObject(appManager)
        .environmentObject(dataManager)
}



Should be @State var navigationPath

Why are you centralising the navigation path into a single AppManager instance? Each tab should have its own NavigationStack, and each NavigationStack should have its own navigation path.

malhal: Thanks, but that does not lead to expected behavior. Ifaik, @State is only relevant for views not for ObservedObjects. Do you have more information?

You can fix it by adding a little delay.
First Change the Tab, then after a fraction of a second change the path.
Here is the code for SomeView2:
struct SomeView2: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var appManager: AppManager
            
    var body: some View {
        Button("Segue to someItem") {
            let someItem = DataManager.instance.dataArray[2]
            
            // First change the Tab.
            appManager.tabSelection = 1
            
            // Then change the path.
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                appManager.navigationPath.append(someItem)
            }
        }
    }
}


Thanks. That does solve the problem. Do you have any additional information to explain this behavior? What keeps me wondering is that I do not need a delay when direct switching to SomeView2 and opening the item, like so:
This works fine and as expected:
SomeView1 -> (changing tab) -> SomeView2 -> (clicking button) -> DataDetailView(someItem)

You're welcome. I suspect the issue you encountered lies in how SwiftUI manages its views. It's important to consider the system's design and user interaction patterns. For example, a user typically taps a tab (or view) before a new view is pushed. Does it make sense? The delay we added basically puts things in order instead of changing everything at once, which could confuse the system and result in unexpected behavior of an empty view.
